# How do I extract images from bundle with specific names and add to array,

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bundle

In my app bundle, I have several images of several items.

ItemA_largepicture.png

ItemA_smallPicture.png

ItemA_overViewPicture.png

ItemB_largepicture.png

ItemB_smallPicture.png

ItemB_overViewPicture.png

ItemC_largepicture.png

ItemC_smallPicture.png

ItemC_overViewPicture.png

...

I want to extract, for example all ItemB pictures,to display in scrollView.
I can easily get one by doing following

```
    path=[ItemB stringByAppendingString:@"_largePicture];
    NSString *imagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:path ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    [self.image setImage:image];
```

So the question is simply; how do I get all the ItemB pictures?
Do I need to put them into an array? and how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code should list everything in your mainBundle

```
NSString *bundleRootPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSArray *bundleRootContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRootPath error:nil];
NSArray *files = [bundleRootContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self beginswith 'ItemA' OR self beginswith 'ItemB' OR self beginswith 'ItemC'"]]; //you can provide your string in ' ' to filter specific content
NSLog(@"%@",files);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpfull. Now I wonder if you could help me to take this one step further. Lets say that all ItemA images were in a folder that was named "ItemA" and so on. I would guess using "bundleWithPath:@"ItemA" insted of "mainBundle", but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
largePicturePath=[ItemB stringByAppendingString:@"_largePicture];
smallPicturePath=[ItemB stringByAppendingString:@"_smallPicture];
overViewPicturePath=[ItemB stringByAppendingString:@"_overViewPicture];
NSString *largeImagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:largePicturePath ofType:@"png"];
NSString *smallImagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:smallPicturePath ofType:@"png"];
NSString *overViewImagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:overViewPicturePath ofType:@"png"];

NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:largeImagePath,smallImagePath,overViewImagePath,nil];

NSEnumerator *e = [imageArray objectEnumerator];

NSString *path;
while (path= [e nextObject]) {
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    ...

}
```